# How can I use weighted log_loss as SCORING function for linear_model.SGDClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, computer-vision, logistic-regression, weighted

I am using

`linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log',class_weight='balanced')`

for 10 classes classification (the classes are very unbalanced).

It looks like that class_weight is used only at training time (in the loss function). They are not used for scoring. 
Thus, I am using

`GridSearchCV(test_model, my_hyperparameters, scoring='f1_macro')`

since 'f1_macro' it calculates "metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account."

I would like to use 'neg_log_loss' as scoring. So, I would have:

`GridSearchCV(test_model, my_hyperparameters, scoring='neg_log_loss')`.

Is it possible to make it weighted?

In the docs I see:

`sklearn.metrics.log_loss(y_true, y_pred, eps=1e-15, normalize=True, sample_weight=None, labels=None)`.

But how can I pass "sample_weight" in

`GridSearchCV(test_model, my_hyperparameters, scoring='neg_log_loss')`?

Comment: You can use `make_scorer` to create a scoring function and pass `sample_weight` as an argument to it.